# What are Intent Filters exactly?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I've read lots of articles about intent filters and I really can't understand exactly what they do?

so please if anybody can explain to me with a clear example what is the role of intent filters exactly ?

thanks

Comment: I believe its no problem when a one can't figure something out due to misunderstanding

Comment: here's a post about it http://android-pro.blogspot.com/search/label/Intent%20Filters

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it's well documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).  Summarizing, when (e.g.) you pass an intent to Context.startActivity, or Context.startService, or broadcast it with Context.sendBroadcast, etc, what activity or service (or, what set of broadcast receivers) is the intent delivered to?

Answer: if the intent is "explicit", i.e., it has the component name field set, then it's delivered to the target component it designates -- this typically happens in communication within an application.

Otherwise ("implicit" intent, as is typical for communication *between* applications), Android must determine the best activity or service (or set of receivers) on its own.  How does Android do that?  That's where filters come in, and I quote:

> It does so by comparing the contents
>   of the Intent object to intent
>   filters, structures associated with
>   components that can potentially
>   receive intents. Filters advertise the
>   capabilities of a component and
>   delimit the intents it can handle.
>   They open the component to the
>   possibility of receiving implicit
>   intents of the advertised type. If a
>   component does not have any intent
>   filters, it can receive only explicit
>   intents. A component with filters can
>   receive both explicit and implicit
>   intents.

The web page in question continues with many details and, at the end, a complete, simple example, and I think it would be redundant to copy and paste them here.

Comment: Can you please give me an example with code to an implicit intent that can be handled by many activies and how intent filters can limit handling to only one activity ?

Comment: @Mina, how could I add any value to the Note Pad example at the page I already pointed to, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html ?!  It has three activities, each with intent filters, and very clear explanation (the "code" is actually all XML, of course).  Normalizing the explanation text to reasonable-length lines, it's over 200 lines (nobody ever accused XML of being too concise;-) -- what would be the added value of copying and pasting that huge amount of text that you can perfectly well read online yourself?!

Comment: Thanks Alex, but what I wanted is an example of an Intent that can be handled by multiple activities

Comment: @Mina, many of the example intents on the page in question _could_ be received by multiple activities, so the "best" one is picked (only broadcasts actually _go_ to multiple components -- for activities and services, only "the best one" is ever picked).

Comment: @AlexMartelli so can I say intent-filter is used for communication or service request from outside the application?

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, Intent filters are a way of telling the OS how to launch/communicate with the different activities/services/broadcast receivers in your app.  So for example, if you want links that start with http://www.mycompany.com to lead people into your app, an intent filter is the way to accomplish that.  Once its setup, anytime someone clicks on a link that starts with that (in any app) the user will be presented with the option to use your app to view that page.  You've probably seen this with youtube urls.   Likewise, if you want the 'share' link commonly seen in many apps to list your app, would use an intent filter to do that.

hope this helps...

Comment: Can you please give me an example to such an Intent Filter

Answer (score 4):

An [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) lets the system know what data or service requests a component can handle.  A component might be an activity, service or broadcast receiver.

If you are writing an image viewer, you would add an intent filter (or several) to the manifest describing the images you can handle.  If you are writing a file browser, you might package up the details of an image file in an intent, and the system would sift through intent filters until it found a best match to handle that image.  The same goes for any type of data or service that might be passed from one component to the next.

Answer (score 4):

**Intent Filters is a way of telling OS that let me handle/provide these kind of Activities/Services**

By adding given filter to Manifest tells OS that i can also handle Sms service and whenever you send sms it will show in a list or you can also explicitly use this as your sms service.

```
<intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

    <action android:name="com.example.code.SMS_INTENT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="smsto" />

</intent-filter>
```

And to explicitly using this service call it like  ...

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.code.SMS_INTENT", Uri.parse(uri));

 intent.putExtra("from", "code");

 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

IntentFilters are used to declare a pattern of Intent attributes that the declaring component will respond to. You can specify with an IntentFilter that a given Activity, Service or BroadcastReceiver will respond to a combination of action, data mime type, scheme, path, etc. For example if you register an Activity with IntentFilter for ACTION_SEND with data type "text/plain", your Activity will be called each time the users wants to send some text.

Answer (score 3):

> intentFilters advertise the capabilities of a component and delimit
>   the intents that can handle. an IntentFilter that a given Activity,
>   Service or BroadcastReceiver will respond to a combination of action,
>   data mime type, scheme, path, etc.
>
> The intent by comparing the intent to intent filters based on three
>   aspects:
>
> 1:- The intent action
>  2:- The intent data (both URI and data type) 
>  3:- The intent
>   category
>
> **action :**
>  Declares the intent action accepted, in the name
>   attribute. The value must be the literal string value of an action,
>   not the class constant.
>
> **data :**
>  Declares the type of data accepted, using one or more
>   attributes that specify various aspects of the data URI (scheme, host,
>   port, path, etc.) and MIME type.
>
> **category :**
>  Declares the intent category accepted, in the name
>   attribute. The value must be the literal string value of an action,
>   not the class constant.

For example, This activity handles "SEND" actions with text data.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: we use `intent-filter` to handle the request from outside the application?

Comment: Yes, When your app is installed on a device, the system identifies your intent filters and adds the information to an internal catalog of intents supported by all installed apps.

Comment: So just to confirm. If we are not going to handle external requests from the other applications. then we don't need to use `intent-filter`?

Comment: No, We need intent-filter for sure. To start new tasks in your application you need to mention Filters with "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and other intents with default "android.intent.category.DEFAULT". Even if you do not mention category.DEFAULT android applies for all implicit intents as DEFAULT only

Answer (score 0):

Intent filter tells the android system for which intent or event the android components(activity,service ,broadcast receiver) should listen.